# JSON data - completion handler

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am new to iOS development and need help on below issue.
I have the below code that downloads a JSON data from web and populates an array with that.

```
let urlPath = "……………………………"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

       if (error != nil) {
            println(error)
        } else {

        let jsonResult: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)!

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            for var i = 0; i < jsonResult.count; i++ {
                self.sales[i] = jsonResult[i]["daily_sales"] as NSString
            }
        }
        }
        })

    task.resume()

    println(self.sales[0])
```

at the end the app crashes since it does not wait for the JSON data to be downloaded.

What are the alternative ways to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It crashes because of this `println(self.sales[0])`. You trying to display sales that are not even downloaded. Put this line at the end of your completion block and you should be OK

Comment: thanks for the tip.. how about if I want to call the sales array within another functions?

Comment: you should be sure they have been downloaded first. Or at least check your array is not empty before trying to call a non-existant index on it.